# disable past date in datepicker wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

How can i disable past date in date picker?I am using ModernUI for my desktop application

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Name="datepicker"  SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" />
```

Comment: You can refer `DatePicker.DisplayDateStart` article on MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: <DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Name="datepicker" DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" ></DatePicker>
  Thanks @GauravKP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @GauravKP for your help.
I used   xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" for getting Current date as

```
 SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
```

and using `DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"` to hide previous date.

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Name="datepicker" DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" ></DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

at codebehind you can define display date like this

```
datepicker.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Now;
```